# Android app using a library/jar from any Java Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I've been looking for a way to work on a few Eclipse projects when developing a web apps and an Android app. My problem is that one of the projects (that contain DTOs or Utils classes) cannot be used (referenced) directly in the Android project.

I found that I need to declare my project as "Is Library" (in the projects properties, under the "Android" section") and then reference it in my Android project (in the same "Android" section of the project's properties). My problem is that I created the needed project as a simple Java (web) project and so, it doesn't have the "Android" section at the Properties window. More than that, I tried creating a .jar file (by exporting that project's sources and classes) but even though it there are no compile errors, that Android app won't run (mainly, as i understand, that's because the .jar contains classes compiled with the Java standard compiler and not the Dalvik machine). whats strange is that I've found some people saying that including the source code, when exporting the jar, worked!

So, I looked for a way to set my dependencies so I won't be forced to have duplicate code, but haven't found a solution yet.

Is there a way to declare an existing Java (Web) project, also as an Android Library ? Or what else can I do ?

Comment: When you right-click on project name in eclipse, there is an option Configure (next to last in mine) which allows you to convert the project to another type of project. Did you try that?

Comment: The "Configure" options does not contain anything related to Android project conversion (or something related). What option should I see here ?

Comment: I have not used Android specific functionality. Then you best bet would probably to create a new project with the write properties and import the source into it. Alternatively you could delete project without deleting underlying source (back up first!!!) and create a new project in the same directory and with the same name with the right config (but again, back up first!!!).

Comment: After looking for a while, I don't think there is a good solution for now. I hope that deleting and recreating the project will not be an issue, because that specific project is also a web project (with some of the configurations created with GPE plugin).